# Azure B2C Implicit Flow not working in ASP.NET when "Access Token" is disabled on the app registration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure-ad-b2c

I'm testing authentication for a server based web app.

I think the best way to login the browser is with Implicit Flow to obtain only an id_token via an HTTP POST.

I've configured my `OpenIdConnectAuthentiationOptions` like:

```
Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
ResponseMode = OpenIdConnectResponseMode.FormPost,
```

These should be the options to do what I am asking.

When I try to authenticate, I am given the error:

> 'AADB2C90057: The provided application is not configured to allow the
> 'OAuth' Implicit flow.

But, I have enabled Implicit Flows in the app registration in Azure AD B2C. However, I specifically am NOT enabling "Access Token," because obviously I am NOT requesting one.

[image]

I'm specifically following the instructions to select only "ID tokens," for web apps using hybrid authentication.

If I change the option to `ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken` I have the same issues. Although, I think this response type also requests an Access Code.

If I enable both ID Tokens and Access Tokens, then the app logs in fine. Why do I have to enable "Access Tokens" when I am only requesting an ID Token?

The basis for what I am attempting is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Important note from [OAuth 2.0 implicit grant flow  | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#send-the-sign-in-request) which is the same doc which can be obtained by clicking '**`learn more about tokens.`**' hyperlink.

[image]
**`NOTE:`**
[image]

Which says we need to ***check both idtoken and accesstoken*** to obtain id token  or access token or in combination of both, but the response depends on the `responseType` mentioned in the authentication request (you may read same document further for the details).
i.e.;

1. You will  receive ***`idtoken`*** , if you have given  **`responsetype =id_token`**
2. You will receive accesstoken if responseType=token
3. You will receive  code and id token in case of responsetype is
   id_token+code

[***Request an ID token as well or hybrid flow***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-id-token-as-well-or-hybrid-flow)

Comment: You are probably correct here. The note is not clear from Microsoft. And it's very misleading to offer an option to enable/disable both the Access Tokens and the ID Tokens. If both have to be enabled for any implicit grant flow to work, then it is absolutely pointless to have these two options separated. So, while you may be correct here, the design, documentation, and behavior are, at best, faulty or misleading. The only other explanation is that you are not correct, and there is a reason both options exist.